# Why is my Ajax callback being processed too soon?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a general ajax function which I'm calling from loads of places in my code. It's pretty standard except for some extra debugging stuff I've recently added (to try to solve this issue), with a global 'ajaxworking' variable:

```
rideData.myAjax = function (url, type, data, successfunc) {
    var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data),
        thisurl = quilkinUrlBase() + url;

    if (ajaxworking.length > 0) {
        console.log(thisurl + ": concurrent Ajax call with: " + ajaxworking);
    }
    ajaxworking = thisurl;
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        data: dataJson,
        url: thisurl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            ajaxworking = '';
            successfunc(response);
        },
        error: webRequestFailed
    });
};
```

Now, there's one section of my code where a second ajax call is made depending on the result of the first:

```
    getWebRides = function (date) {
        var rideIDs = [];
        var intdays = bleTime.toIntDays(date);
        
        rideData.myAjax("GetRidesForDate", "POST", intdays, function (response) {
            rides = response;
            if (rides.length === 0) {
                $('#ridelist').empty();  // this will also remove any handlers
                qPopup.Alert("No rides found for " + bleTime.DateString(date));
                return null;
            }
            $.each(rides, function (index) {
                rideIDs.push(rides[index].rideID);
            });
            GetParticipants(rideIDs);
        });
    },
```

'GetParticipants' (which also calls 'myAjax') works fine - most of the time. But in another part of my code, 'GetWebRides' is itself called directly after another ajax call - i.e. there are 3 calls, each successive one depending on the previous. The 'top-level' call is as follows:

```
rideData.myAjax("SaveRide", "POST", ride, function (response) {
        // if successful, response should be just a new ID
        if (response.length < 5) {
            // document re-arrangement code snipped here for brevity
            getWebRides(date);                      
        }
         else {
            qPopup.Alert(response);
        }
    });
```

so, only when there are three successive calls like this, I'm getting the 'concurrent' catch in the *third* one:

> GetParticipants: concurrent call with GetRidesForDate

and (if allowed to proceed) this causes a nasty probem at the server with datareaders already being open. But why is this only occurring when GetParticipants is called as the third in the chain?

I see, after some research. that there are now other ways of arranging async calls, e.g. using 'Promises', but I'd like to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score -1):

Solved this.
Part of the 'document re-arrangement code' that I had commented out for this post, was in fact calling another Ajax call indirectly (*very* indirectly, hence it took a long time to find).